# SSAS custom total for rates (weighting average)

Tags: ssas

I need to change the total of an interest rate column. I mean, the total in the rate column is summarizing and I need the weighting average instead of the total. for example:

amount..........rate

450000..........8.75

390000..........8

15000...........2

855000(total)...8.29 (weighting average)

I'm trying to do it in the CALCULATIONS tab of the SSAS, but I cannot identify the total level for each group.

Please some ideas, point me to the right direction...

Thanks

JA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a calculation to your source SQL views or DSV to calculate e.g. rate weight = rate * amount.  I would then add that as a normal measure, Sum aggregation, hidden once you have finished testing.

Then the SSAS calculation becomes: rate weight / amount (wrapped in the typical Iif function to avoid dividing by zero).

At the leaf levels this returns weight.  At any summary level it will return weighted average.